# Using weight column in PCA analysis with R

Tags: r, pca, factominer

I have a column in my data file which corresponds to weight of individuals. The data looks like

```
> library(FactoMineR)
> mydata <- read.csv('test.csv', header=T,row.names=1)
> mydata
       V1 V2 V3   WG 
P1.K1 218 30 10 1.00 
P2.K1 218 23 15 0.10  
P2.K2  30 32 17 0.88 
P2.K3   5 12 14 0.02
```

When I use the following command,

```
> res.pca <- PCA(mydata)
```

It uses the WG column as an active variable as can be seen in the figure below.

[image]

On the other hand, if I use

```
> res.pca <- PCA(mydata, quanti.sup=4)
```

I still see WG in the graph of variables.

[image]

I want to exclude that in the PCA analysis as an active variable. Instead I want to use that as weight for each row. So, the weight of `P1.K1` is 1 while the weight of `P2.K2` is 0.88. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`PCA` in `FactoMineR` has an option to provide row weights. I think what you are after is the folowwing.

```
res.pca <- PCA(mydata[, 1:3], row.w = mydata[, 4])
```